# C#, How to configure LocalServer in ArcGISRuntimeSDK

Tags: c#, arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I've tried every possible solution that crossed my mind. I keep getting:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'LocalServer start failed: executable not found.

When I call:

```
Esri.ArcGISRuntime.LocalServices.LocalServerEnvironment.Initialize();
```

I have downloaded and installed Local Server SDK and then Installed the NuGet package of LocalServices. I have also tried adding reference instead of NuGet. I have also read the official documentation. Nothing seems to work.

**P.S.** Also when I initialize the runtime sdk seems to work fine with:

```
Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize();
```

Comment: Does `CheckInstallValid()` return `true` or `false`?

Comment: it returns false

Comment: I'll venture a guess - local server executable should be added to the environment's `PATH` variable in order to be located correctly.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the version of the Local Server SDK you installed matches the version of the LocalServices NuGet package you've installed?

Comment: Ok so it worked. The version and path were the problem indeed. Thank you very much for the help. I will edit my post and explain all the steps to configure it.

Comment: I'm curious why Step 3 is needed. The localserver packages doesn't look at that variable at all. The build-step reads the registry to find the local server install, then xcopy deploys all the required files to the output folder of your app.

Comment: Post your edits as answer and accept it instead of posting it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have solved the issue. Below are the steps on how to configure the SDK:

1. Download and install the local server (take note of your version 100.x)
2. Install NuGet package of Esri LocalServices (make sure it is exact version of local server)
3. Add enviromental variable RUNTIMELOCALSERVER_100_X matching install directory of local server (where you replace X with your version)
4. Call `Esri.ArcGISRuntime.LocalServices.LocalServerEnvironment.Initialize();` and `Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize();` in your `App.xaml.cs` and everything should work fine